# Get Different Results of Running Command on Jenkins Job and on Slave Itself

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I set up a jenkins job to test my PowerShell Script. However, the results I got from building jenkins job are different from running the command on slave.

The following is the result I got from building jenkins job.
[image: Here is the result I get from building jenkins job]

Here are the results I got from running the "Get-Module" command on slave.
[image: Here are the results I got from running the "Get-Module" command on slave]

I didn't mean their output formats are different. I'm supposed to get the same three modules on jenkins job, but there is only one modules output. I have set the %PSModulePath% to exactly the same with the one on my slave. But nothing changed.

Is it the problem with credentials? I actually used the same username and password to login to the slave on jenkins. But I set two ways to access the slave. One is the username and password, the other one is ssh keys. Do they have differences?

Comment: Hi Jillian, from your Jenkins output we can see that you are using 32 bit (x86) PowerShell (reference to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`), which would not be the platform you launch from a default prompt. Running the Jenkins agent as 64 bit (x64) would solve this; the linked question goes over that pretty well.

Comment: @briantist I didn't even notice this issue. I'll look into it. After I put them into one PowerShell session, they worked. Thank you!